# My if-statement seems go even though it's not supposed. PHP & MySQLI

Tags: php, mysqli

I've been trying to handle making a site where you can create an account, and having unique usernames. For the moment, I have an if-statement to check if I get an error while creating an account.

```
function createuser($username,$pass,$namn,$secret,$svar,$connection){
    $query = "INSERT INTO login SET 
    user = '$username',
    pass = '$pass',
    namn = '$namn',
    secretpass = '$svar',
    Question = '$secret'";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
    if (!mysqli_query($connection,$query))
    {
        if(mysqli_error($connection) == "Duplicate entry '$username' for key 'user'")
        {
            echo "This username already exists.";
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that when I make an account, that have an unique username, I still get the "This username already exists". And that is supposed to get executed when I get an error.

Any clue where the problem may be?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just in case you don't know this already, that code is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're doing your query twice:

```
$result = mysqli_query($connection,$query); //query executed here
if (!mysqli_query($connection,$query)) //query re-executed here too
{
    if(mysqli_error($connection) == "Duplicate entry '$username' for key 'user'")
    {
        echo "This username already exists.";
    }
}
```

So regardless of what happens, your "if" statement is always going to be false since if your first query succeeded, re-executing it will yield a false result and if it failed the first time, it'll just fail again the second time.

I think your code should be:

```
$result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
if (!$result) 
{
    if(mysqli_error($connection) == "Duplicate entry '$username' for key 'user'")
    {
        echo "This username already exists.";
    }
}
```

Comment: this was it. Thank you for your reply! I really appreciate it.